# Compare two files and print the common fields and their corresponding line numbers in the 1st file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have some raw data in one file say File1.txt

```
Colt McCoy QB CLE  135 222 1576    6   9   60.8%   74.51  
Josh Freeman QB TB 291 474 3451    25  6   61.4%   95.9  
Matt Cassel QB KC  262 450 3116    27  7   58.2%   93.0  
Michael Vick QB PHI    233 372 3018    21  6   62.6%   100.2  
Matt Schaub QB HOU 365 574 4370    24  12  63.6%   92.0
```

File 2.txt has a list of names, one name per line

```
Josh  
Matt
```

I want to get the output as Name and line number. For the above example it would be:

```
Josh: 2  
Matt: 3,5
```

I have a command which gives me the list of names and the line numbers but I want to print it in the desired format above. My current command is

```
awk '{print $1, NR}' file1.txt | grep -f file2.txt
```

It shows

```
Josh 2
Matt 3
Matt 5
```

What can I do to make it print like the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` alone can do this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$1]=seen[$1]","NR; next};
{if ($1 in seen){printf("%s: %s\n", $1, substr(seen[$1], 2))}}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff -y file1 file2`.

It will give you a side-by-side output from both files.
It also has other options to parse your output.. Review the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) for more options.